# How to set an proxy object in webextension-polyfill [firefox]

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently working on an extension. The extension was done firstly in Chrome and everything works there, but when I try to use the same extension in Firefox I get `Error: DataCloneError: Proxy object could not be cloned`.

I'm using [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) and [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) and both of these libraries uses [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to handle their reactivity.

The special piece of code that is currently breaking my app is:

```
import browser from 'webextension-polyfill'

interface ProjectCodec { id: string; }

export const setProjectForRecording = async (project: ProjectCodec) => {
  await browser.storage.local.set({
    [CURRENT_PROJECT_FOR_RECORDING_KEY]: project
  })
}
```

When I do a `console.log(project)` I get:

```
Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
```

From what it looks like when we use `browser.storage.local.set` we can't pass a `Proxy` object to it. Then I tried:

```
await browser.storage.local.set({
    [CURRENT_PROJECT_FOR_RECORDING_KEY]: Object.assign({}, project)
  })
```

But the same error happens. Is this a bug with the library or am I doing something wrong? I tried a couple other variations of `Object.assign()` but no luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a super [annoying bug in Firefox](https://bugzil.la/1795932) that they claim as intentional behavior, so you'll have to make a clone yourself e.g. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(project))` or a deepCopy function (there are multiple examples around).